# How to deal with more than 60 TextFormField in a single screen in flutter?

Tags: flutter, texteditingcontroller

I am working on an app in which I have to generate PDF based on user input. but there are more than 60 inputs I need to take from user.

So how can i deal with this ?

A common approach I know is to create `TextEditingController` for each fields and pass all 60+ field's data in function body to generate PDF, but I have never used 60+ controllers in a single screen so I am confused how to deal with it.

please let me know better way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to access values within TextFields you have 2 options (afaik):

1. Create 60 `TextEditingController`
2. Create 60 variables (or 1 map, or 1 list), and change these values by taking advantage of the [`onChange`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextField/onChanged.html) property of the [TextField Widget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextField-class.html)

I would personally go with one map having the field title as a key but this is up to you !

Comment: I am trying 2nd one. I will store data in map as I will be able to fetch data using key (as list data can be accessed using index only, so that will be another mess).

Comment: Glad it works for you. Don't forget to upvote and validate the answers if it solved you issue ! :)

Comment: well yeah. it's working as expected. [see image](https://pasteboard.co/JukSz9r.png)   1 more question, How can I  pass these all user inputs to  a function ?

Comment: Just take your map as an argument like: void processUserInputs(Map<String, String> userInputs) {print("Do something");}